# About the high-order derivatives of Lambert function

Tags: special-functions, recurrences

In the mid seventies, in my former research group, we found that the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $W_0(x)$ could write
$$\frac {d^n\,W_0(x)}{dx^n}=(-1)^{n+1}\,\,\frac{\,P_n(w)}{ e^{nw}\,(1+w)^{2n-1}}\qquad \text{with}\qquad w=W_0(x)$$ where, with $P_1(w)=1$, the polynomials

$$P_n(w)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_{n,k}\,w^k$$
satisfy the simple recurrence relation
$$P_{n+1}(w)=\big(n (w + 3) - 1\big)\,P_{n}(w)-(1+w)\,P'_{n}(w)$$

The very first of them
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(w) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & w+2 \\
 3 & 2 w^2+8 w+9 \\
 4 & 6 w^3+36 w^2+79 w+64 \\
 5 & 24 w^4+192 w^3+622 w^2+974 w+625 \\
 6 & 120 w^5+1200 w^4+5126 w^3+11758 w^2+14543 w+7776 \\
 7 & 720 w^6+8640 w^5+45756 w^4+137512 w^3+248250 w^2+255828
   w+117649 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ show some interesting patterns such that
$$a_{n,0}=n^{n-1}$$
$$a_{n,1}= 3n^n-(n+1)^n-n^{n-1}$$
$$a_{n,n-2}=2(n-1)(n-1)!$$
$$a_{n,n-1}=(n-1)!$$

`We were not be able to generate the general recurrence relation for the` $a_{n,k}$ and this should be my first question.

My second question is : `how to prove that` $a_{n,k}$ `are all positve, possibly unimodal and log-concave with respect to` $k$.

Any help, idea or suggestion would be more than welcome.

Comment: see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3216499/130022)

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A042977. These are related to the Ward and the second order Eulerian polynomials (search on A042977 in the OEIS search line.)

Comment: @RenéGy. Thanks a lot for the link !

Comment: @TomCopeland. Thanks a lot for the information !

Answer (score 6):

Both questions are answered in the 2011 [Ph.D. thesis](https://ir.lib.uwo.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=7090&context=digitizedtheses) of G.A. Kalugin, see also [arXiv:1011.5940](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5940)

$$\alpha_{n,k}=\sum_{m=0}^k\frac{1}{m!}{{2n-1}\choose{k-m}}\sum_{q=0}^m(-1)^q (q+n)^{m+n-1}.$$
There are equivalent representations in terms of Stirling numbers or Bernoulli polynomials.

In section 4.2.3 Kalugin proves that the coefficients are positive, unimodal, and log-concave.

Comment: Thank you very much for the references !